# Good way to view matrices and higher dimensional arrays in VScode

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, pytorch, pycharm

When working with PyTorch/numpy and similar packages, is there a good way to view matrices (or, in general, arrays with two or more dimensions) in debug mode, similar to the way Matlab (or even pyCharm if I remember correctly) present it?
This is, for example, a PyTorch tensor, which is very confusing -- opening `H` here gives me the same thing again and again.
[image: PyTorch Tensor]

As opposed to Matlab, where I can watch it like that:
[image: Matlb array]

Would appreciate any help with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make sure you have the Jupyter extension installed and then simply right click the variable in the Debug menu and select the `View Value in Data Viewer` option.

Comment: Thanks! This is almost exactly what I wanted -- the only problem with it is that it's pretty slow and can not work for very large matrices (more than 1000 columns), while Matlab handles those very easily. My guess is that for some reason, the extension tries to load the entire matrix, while I only need (and can view) a small portion of it on the screen at a time, and Matlab only loads this portion. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: There is one possibility that comes to my mind. If you are only interested in a small part of the array, you can open up the Debug Console and create new variable that is a slice of the original array, then visualize the new variable. For example enter `x = original[10:20, 30:40]` to Debug Console and now visualize `x`. I have tested it and it is fast.

Answer (score 0):

From within a Jupyter Notebook click Variables then there's a little icon to the left of the variable with a tooltip that says 'Show variable snapshot in data viewer'

Comment: Thanks! That's almost exactly what I wanted. Could you please see my comment to @MarGenDo? Maybe you'd have a good idea to solve that issue? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't.  Good luck.